# Generators function

Tags: python, iterator, generator

```
MAX_STUDENTS = 50

def get_student_ids():
  student_id = 1
  while student_id <= MAX_STUDENTS:
    # Write your code below
    n = yield student_id
    if n != None:
      student_id = n
      continue


    student_id += 1

student_id_generator = get_student_ids()
for i in student_id_generator:
  # Write your code below
  if i == 1:
    i = student_id_generator.send(25)
  print(i)
```

Im quite confused, when i run the code below, i understand the the send function gives 25 as the yield value and assigns it to n, however when entering the if statement, checking if n is not None, wouldnt this create an infinite loop, since n is not none, would take us to the continue statement, which takes us back to the next iteration of the while loop, completely skipping the incrementing of student id

Comment: `n` only receives the value 25 on one iteration of the loop.  `i` is definitely never equal to 1 after that point, so `.send()` never gets called again.  On all subsequent iterations of the `while` loop, `n` receives the default None.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing one can notice is that `n` will always be of type `none` except when you send 25 into the generator.

Let's look at the flow of the program

this is the driver code at the start of the program

```py
student_id_generator = get_student_ids() #creates a generator class
for i in student_id_generator: #interates through the generator class
    if i == 1: # note that the first i == 1, so the first time the code hits 
               #this condition, it will be true 
        i = student_id_generator.send(25) #sets n to be 25
    print(i) #for the first iteration, will return 1, as the first yield is 1
```

now, since n=25 (you just sent 25 into the generator code), let's look at the generator

```
n = yield student_id # n=25
if n != None: #since n==25, n is not none
    student_id = n #student_id = 25
    continue #go back to the while loop
student_id += 1 # will not be run
```

Now that student_id = 25, for the next iteration in the driver code, it will yield 25, so 25 will be printed. **But** n will be `None` as nothing is sent to the generator, so `student_id += 1` will be run. From there, the while loop kicks in and it will continue until 'student_id == 50', where the loop breaks.

Will there be an infinite loop? No. Because the condition 'n != None' only occurs once.

I hope this helps. If you are still confused, my suggestion is to take out a pen and paper and work out what happens to the code step by step. I did that to help myself understand it.